# How to analyse an impulse response function with more than 2 variables?

Tags: r, var, economics

I am running an impulse response function in R, using the package vars.

My data has 3 variables, the inflation (Brazilian CPI, or IPCA), the exchange rate and the output gap.

My goal is to calculate the exchange rate pass-through (both the maximum impact and the lag), and I am following and academic recommendation to add the output gap (as the monthly industrial production with HP filter).

The pass-through I am interested in is exchange rate -> CPI. The output gap is of my interest only in the way it impacts this pass-through relation. So I wrote the code as:

```
model_irf  <- vars::irf(model_var,  
                          impulse = "Exchange Rate", 
                          response = "CPI", 
                          n.ahead = 12, 
                          cumulative = TRUE)
```

This gives me the expected response of variable “CPI” t+12 to a unit change in variable “Exchange Rate”.

[image]

I imagine (from macroeconomic theory) the output gap impacts the magnitude of the pass through, so in periods of larger output gap companies have less space to increase prices; relation that is not visible in this model I wrote.

My question is: How is the output gap related to the IRF I calculated? (Or if the model is wrong and I should write it differently to test this assumption)

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Seems like you are asking a data modeling question rather than a specific programming question. Such questions are better addressed at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic

Comment: Thank you very much @MrFlick! I didn't know that forum. 
Anyways, I would really appreciate some help with the programming/R package part. I believe I am not using the function/VAR model right